# Provide that $3(a^5+b^7\sin\frac{\pi a}{2}+c)-2(ab+bc+ca)\leq 4 $

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $a,b,c  \in [0,1]$, prove that
$$ f(a,b,c) = 3(a^5+b^7\sin\frac{\pi a}{2}+c)-2(ab+bc+ca)\leq 4 $$

P.S: I spent all my Sunday morning to solve it, but I didn't have any progress!!
I just think we can use analytic to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

$$ f(a,b,c) = 3(a^5+b^7\sin \frac{\pi a}{2}+c)-2(ab+bc+ca)$$

First we see that $g(a) = 3a^5-2a(b+c)$ has maximum at $a=0$ for which we get $$f(0,b,c)=3c-2bc \leq 3c\leq 3<4$$

or at $a=1$ for which we get $$f(1,b,c) = 3+3b^7+c-2b-2bc$$ So we have to check if $$c(1-2b)\leq 1-3b^7+2b$$ for all $b,c\in[0,1]$. Can you finish now?

---

- If $b\leq 1/2$ then it is enough, since $c\in [0,1]$ to check if $$1-2b\leq 1-3b^7+2b \iff 3b^6\leq 4$$ which is true since $b\leq 1$.
- If $b\geq 1/2$ then it is enough, since $c\geq 0$ to check if $$0\leq 1-3b^7+2b $$

But this is also true since it ise equivalent to: $$(b-1)(3b^6+3b^5+3b^4+3b^3+3b^2+3b+1)\leq0$$

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

$f$ is a linear function of $c$ and $f$ is a convex function of $b$, which says that it's enough our inequality for $\{b,c\}\in\{0,1\}$ and the rest is smooth.